# Есть ли разница между предлогами "вследствие" и "в связи"?

Tags: этимология, лексика, семантика, синонимы

*Я, Василий Пупкин, не посетил рабочее место **вследствие/в связи с** непогоды(-ой).*

Какой предлог будет предпочтительнее в этом предложении? Мне кажется, что *вследствие* в данном контексте — значит после того, как я увидел плохую погоду, подумал и в итоге никуда не пошел. А *в связи* — это что-то вроде того, что непогода застала меня врасплох, и мне пришлось оставить затею куда-либо идти.

Comment: Жаль, что нельзя обоим участникам галочку поставить: оба ответа по-своему хороши.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**В связи с** — предлог, который может использоваться для описания действия, обозначенного глаголом любого времени и вида:

В связи с плохой погодой я не пойду, думаю не пойти, решил не ходить, не пошел на работу.

**Вследствие** — предлог, который уместен для описания действия, обозначенного глаголом прошедшего времени и совершенного вида:

Я не пошел на работу, не дошел до работы, не мог пойти на работу вследствие плохой погоды.

Answer (score 4):

На мой взгляд, разница есть: в первом случае у вас семантическое подчинение, ваше действие (прогул) обусловлено внешним императивом (погодой), выстроена цепочка зависимости. Второй же случай описывает семантическое равноправие.
Фактически, у собеседника в первом случае возникает впечатление неодолимого препятствия, во втором - у прогульщика был выбор.

Answer (score 2):

*Смысловая* разница в том, что "**вследствие**" указывает на *объективную причину* происходящего или уже произошедшего (синонимично: по причине того-то);

"**в связи**" лишь объясняет *действия, намерения или пожелания* человека обстоятельством *произвольного* характера (объективным или субъективным, происходящим, произошедшим или предполагаемым в будущем), указываемым в качестве причины, одной из причин или повода.

Соответственно, в данном случае выгоднее сослаться на объективную причину ("вследствие"):

> Я, В.П., не смог вовремя прибыть к месту работы **вследствие** дорожной аварии .

("*в связи с аварией*" можно истолковать по-разному, напр. опоздавший загляделся на разборку между владельцами помятых машин)

> Прошу уволить меня по собственному желанию **в связи с** переходом на
>   другую работу.